# how can I increase the connections for mongoose in nodejs

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I need to run 10 queries simultaneously. How do I do that in my nodejs application. What I am doing right now is

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb', function(err) {
if(err) {
    console.log(err);
} else {
    console.log('Connected to the database');
}
});
```

What should I do to solve the problem. Or should I change something in the db configuration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can increase the poolsize while connecting. Try This

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/testdb', {server: { poolSize: 50 }}, function(err) {
if(err) {
    console.log(err);
} else {
    console.log('Connected to the database');
}
});
```